# Detect changes in html tree

Tags: php, html, tree, structure

I'm looking for a fast and efficient way to detect changes to a page HTML structure. This doesn't include text/strings within the html elements.

From all my research online I haven't been able to find any good method..

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: Yes, but I need to achieve it serverside. In PHP prefably.

Comment: the only way I see it, is to use that solution, but to add callback function with ajax. that ajax will notify your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Re your comment:

> Yes, but I need to achieve it serverside. In PHP prefably.

You **have** to use Javascript for this, and it **has** to run client-side. There is no option about that.

If you want to make PHP aware of it, then you will still have to use Javascript to detect it, and then use a Javascript Ajax call back to your server.